# Mesh not moving with armature modifier

Tags: armature, weight-painting

In a nutshell: I'm working on making some slight changes to the body mesh below and I will be creating some transparent clothes to go on top and the mesh is not moving with the modifier.

I've had this happen before with a top and boots as well, both work in game but I'd love not to have to load my game up to check constantly. I'm using the armature modifier as normal and with some bones I select, the whole object goes purple in weight paint mode and nothing moves with those bones.

With others that work, you can see the bone/vertex group it selects from the list and the weight paint looks normal/the model is blue.
Now with this knee bone as an example, it comes up purple when I select it, but you can see there is weight painting in that area under the 'thigh' group. So why isn't it behaving like it?

Bind to Vertex Groups is checked and Object is set to rig in the modifier.

Pelvis, auto selected when I clicked that bone, working when I move it:
[image]

Leg bone, purple mesh, not working. My object doesn't move with it:
[image]

Thigh weight paint near that area on my object:
[image]

I've had this happen a couple of times and I'm not sure what's up. Makes it difficult to see if things are working pre in game testing. I haven't touched the weight paint, this is just a nude body mesh!

Please ignore the titles of the vertex groups being different, I'm using script to do something unrelated.

Comment: sometimes the parenting doesn't work and you have to make some correction, either with in Weight Paint mode or with Vertex Groups assignment

Comment: Sometimes when I'm working with armatures, one of the bones wont work. My first thought is if the deform option in the bones tab is unchecked. You could try checking that out.